# Which character is used for the numpad dot-key by default?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

Well this will be a very simple question.

I just bought an English-Keyboard with qwerty layout because I love the English layout much more than the German one. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

The numpad on my new keyboard has labeled the dot `.`. Nevertheless I get alway a comma `,`.

The keyboard has a UK-Layout. The 'Region & Language' settings look like this:

[image: Region and Language]

I expected to get a dot and wonder if this is normal?

**Which character is used for the numpad dot-key by default?**